# jQuery: Is there a functional difference between $('.selector', myContext) and myContext.find('.selector')?

Tags: jquery

I feel like `$('.selector', myContext)` and `myContext.find('.selector')` are two identical ways to get the same information. Is there a practical reason when you would use one over the other? Speed perhaps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$('.selector', myContext)` and `$(myContext).find('.selector')` are completely equivalent:

From the jQuery 1.4.2 source ([core.js](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/core.js#L146)):

```
//...

// HANDLE: $(expr, context)
// (which is just equivalent to: $(context).find(expr)
} else {
    return jQuery( context ).find( selector );
}

//...
```

Comment: I do remember a blog post or something, probably from John Resig, that deprecates the "context" second-parameter style.

Comment: @Pointy if you could find a link, would you mind posting here?  I've used the context param before and like to tune my coding practices to the recommended way.

Comment: @jinglesthula I'll see if I can find it. It's at least true that internally the library performs the two-parameter version by calling `.find()`.

Answer (score 3):

> Internally, selector context is
>   implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to
>   $(this).find('span').

From: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Answer (score 1):

The first involves slightly less characters of code, but other than that the same thing

Answer (score 0):

When a new jQuery object is created the constructor tries to figure out what was passed in. When context is a DOMElement jQuery transforms $(selector, context) into $(context).find(selector). 
You can avoid much of the logic the constructor does including some string parsing by making this change yourself.
(excerpt from the following post :
http://engineeredweb.com/blog/10/12/3-tips-make-your-jquery-selectors-faster/
)